# Specified Cast Invalid with DataRow value

Tags: .net, sql, datetime, datatable

I'm a little stumped with an error I am getting when moving my site from local to a web server. On local I get no error with this code, on the web server I get "Specified Cast is not valid".

The line of code throwing the error is:

```
DateTime expirationDate = (DateTime)dtUser.Rows[0]["PasswordExpirationDate"];
```

I thought this was a valid way to get a DateTime from a database and use it in C#. I have verified the value is not null, currently it comes out as 2013-11-18 16:41:41.937

I have already tried switching to Convert.ToDateTime(dtUser.Rows[0]["PasswordExpirationDate"]) and that fails as well, with and without a .ToString() added.

I can't find a reason the web server throws this error and local does not. Would anyone have a better way to get this value, or any ideas as to what the issue could be with the web server?

Comment: So is it a string(varchar) or DateTime in database? How do you fill it, with a DataAdapter or manually? Is the database schema the same or different?

Comment: It is a DateTime in the database. It is filled with a SqlDataAdapter. These sites are both using the same database, so the schema is the same.

Comment: What means "it comes out as 2013-11-18 16:41:41.937". Is it a string in the `DataTable`? How does the sql-query look like, are you really selecting the datetime-field without conversion to varchar?

Comment: If I catch it in debugger I see the value I gave above. If I put a watch on this, dtUser.Rows[0]["PasswordExpirationDate"], it looks like a DateTime to me in the window. I see the properties of a DateTime object, not a string or anything else. Honestly it looks like it shouldn't even need a cast. 

The query is "SELECT PasswordExpirationDate FROM Users WHERE UserID = @UserID"

Answer (score 1):

Please use culture,it will help you.

```
string result = Convert.ToDateTime(dtUser.Rows[0["PasswordExpirationDate"].toString(),
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: If it's a `datetime` in the database, converting it to and from strings is more likely to introduce bugs than solve them.

Comment: This won't work, I need it to be a DateTime to use for getting timespan and such later on.

Comment: I don't convert it to a string. If I try simply using dtUser.Rows[0]["PasswordExpirationDate"], I get an error saying I am missing a cast. So I started casting the value which only worked locally. I only tried converting it to a string and back to fix the error, which had no effect.

Comment: @CoreyT: Please try newly edited. I got same issue for int conversion on server not in local. May it will help you.